# How can I get sed to remove `\` followed by anything?

Tags: sed

I am trying to write a `sed` script to convert LaTeX coded tables into tab delimited tables.

To do this I need to convert `&` into `\t` and strip out anything that is preceded by `\`.

This is what I have so far:

```
s/&/\t/g
s/\*/" "/g
```

The first line works as intended.  In the second line I try to replace `\` followed by anything with a space but it doesn't alter the lines with `\` in them.

Any suggestions are appreciated.  Also, can you briefly explain what suggested scripts "say"?  I am new to `sed` and that really helps with the learning process!

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you're running this as a sed script, and not directly on the command line:

```
s/\\.*/ /g
```

Explanation:

`\\` - double backslash to match a literal backslash (a single `\` is interpreted as "escape the following character", followed by a `.*` (`.` - match any single character, `*` - arbitrarily many times).

Answer (score 1):

You need to escape the backslash as it is a special character.
If you want to denote "any character" you need to use . (a period)

the second expression should be:

```
s/\\.//g
```

I hope I understood your intention and you want to strip the character after the backslash,
if you want to delete all the characters in the line after the backslash add a star (*)
after the period.